# Mobile native app load testing free ware

Tags: mobile

Is there any any free ware like jmeter that can perform load testing of mobile native apps.
I know it can be done using loadrunner or neoload but iam looking for some freeware tools.

Thanks and Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

50 user version of HP LoadRunner.

100 thread version of SOASTA CloudTest lite.

If you find that some tools have value in your work yet you are unwilling to recognize this value with a purchase then this is problematic.